# Using @babel/register for a React app in Node v13

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

I have an app built using `create-react-app` and it has an entrypoint that used something like this —

```js
require('babel-register')({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ['es2015', 'react-app'],
  plugins: [
    'syntax-dynamic-import',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel'
  ]
});
require('./index');
```

I'm in the process of upgrading Node (from v8 to v13.5) and decided to upgrade Babel too. Using Babel 7, the above piece of code was rewritten as —

```js
require('@babel/register')({
  ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env', 'react-app'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    'dynamic-import-node',
    'react-loadable/babel'
  ],
});
require('./index');
```

Now when I run this, I get the error —

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1160
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /my-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /my-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js from /my-app/server/controllers/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename asyncToGenerator.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /my-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/package.json.
```

I'm guessing this is because `preset-env` is using modules support as it is detecting it in my version of Node (v13.6.0). If that's how I can fix this issue, how do I force it to use the `es2015` preset? They've long been deprecated in favor of `preset-env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon [this comment](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/9920#issuecomment-487537396) on the Babel project's issue tracker that says `BABEL_ENV` should be set to `test` to transpile modules.

The relevant code from the linked comment is [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app/create.js#L69-L92) —

```js
[
    isEnvTest && [
        // ES features necessary for user's Node version
        require('@babel/preset-env').default,
        {
            targets: {
                node: 'current',
            },
        },
    ],
    (isEnvProduction || isEnvDevelopment) && [
        // Latest stable ECMAScript features
        require('@babel/preset-env').default,
        {
            // Allow importing core-js in entrypoint and use browserlist to select polyfills
            useBuiltIns: 'entry',
            // Set the corejs version we are using to avoid warnings in console
            // This will need to change once we upgrade to corejs@3
            corejs: 3,
            // Do not transform modules to CJS
            modules: false,
            // Exclude transforms that make all code slower
            exclude: ['transform-typeof-symbol'],
        },
    ]
]
```

Setting `BABEL_ENV` to `test` fixes my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using geolib library. Please try upgrading your geolib dependency to 3.2.x. The "type": "module" flag has been removed from 3.1.x -> 3.2.x

or try changing he node version to `12.11.1, 12.12.0`

Refer the discussion here https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib/issues/208

Comment: I dont think its a geolib issue

Answer (score 0):

You can either downgrade to Node v10 or add this to the existing one

```
  "start": "node --experimental-modules src/index.mjs "
```